# Highlighting in elasticsearch: giving extra fragment

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, solaris, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to use the highlighting functionality provided in elasticsearch.
Here are the basic configurations done:
1) I am using term vector highlight.
2) Below is the highlight key of my query:

```
   :highlight=>{
   :pre_tags=>["<span style=\"background-color:yellow\">"],
   :post_tags=>["</span>"],
   :fields=>{
   :text=>{
   :type=>"fvh",
   :boundary_max_scan=>300,
   :boundary_chars=>"\n",
   :number_of_fragments=>100
   }}}

 So I am using "fvh" highlighter, boundary max scan of 300 and boundary char set as "\n".
```

Now say below is an example data:
   "Hello How are you. Where were you dude. Did you just say Hello. Ya I did"
And I search for hello with the above highlighter.

It returns two fragments:
1. **Hello** How are you. Where were you dude. Did you just say Hello

2.Did you just say ***Hello***. Ya I did

So in the first fragment the second "hello" is not highlighted but it is captured in the second fragment.

Can some one please tell the cause of this behavior as to why is this giving an extra fragment . Instead it could have highlighted both "hello" in a single fragment.

Comment: Fairly sure that's working as intended.  I believe the "plain" highlighter merges contiguous fragments though, so you could use that, instead.

Comment: I tried with plain highlighter. That is good but with that I dont have the option to change fragment size, offset and other parameters that term vector highlighting gives